# Link entity reference field to reference type or node

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Is there a way I can output the link of an entity reference aside from displaying the label. I have an entity reference field that links to a page node content type. I'm trying to figure out how I can output the link. The image below are nodes

[image]

Here is the sample of the code I've just created. It shows the label of the entity but it does not come with link.

I tried using `entity.uri.value` or just `entity.uri` to output the url

```
<a href="{{ url('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}"> {{ list.entity.label }} </a>
```

---

```
                {% if node.field_academic_experience_ref.entity.label != node.label %}
                    <div class="program-details">
                        <h3>Academic Experience</h3>

                        <ul>
                            {% for list in node.field_academic_experience_ref %}
                                <li>{{ list.entity.label }}</li> 
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>

                        {#                             
                        {{ node.field_program_details.value | raw }} 
                        #}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm still stuck trying to solve my problem. Can my problem be solved using Drupal views?